# Can I check for HTTPS in Magento PHTML files?

Tags: php, magento

I am installing Clicky code on a Magento website. I would like to use their HTTPS tracker only on HTTPS enabled pages of Magento. How can I do this?

I tried

```
<?php if($_SERVER['https'] == 'on') : ?>
```

but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions on identifying HTTPS pages will be of great help!

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note to the answer below, can't you just omit the protocol?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Magento actually provides a method for this for you.

Use this to check whether you are in secure mode:

```
// check to see if your store is in secure mode
$isSecure = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure();
```

Comment: <?php if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()): ?>
<!--YES-->
<?php else : ?>
<!--NO-->
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: I used this option as I like to use the inbuilt solution. I'm sure the other methods work as well. Thanks a lot to everyone who answered.

Comment: not exactly sure why, but this doesn't seem to be working in IE8. All other browsers are ok. anyone else has similar issues?

Comment: @GergelyVarga it's unlikely to be IE8 itself. I'd suspect caching or some other variable instead

Comment: Agree. The error was in the "Custom Menu" module, but only IE8 complained about the unsecure URL on the secure page.

Comment: We can also use this , in case of store front template files, (i personally prefer this and strongly recommend)                $isSecure = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure();          ($isSecure) ? : 'https://' : 'http://'

Comment: Joe nailed it. In particular, `isCurrentlySecure` in `"app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php" line 1259`checks for both overwrite offload header in XML configuration and the standard check of HTTPS, e.g. `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'Off';`.

Answer (score 5):

**Native Magento solution**

```
$isSecure = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure(); 
($isSecure) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

This helps to check whether your store front is in https or http

Answer (score -4):

This may seem like a bit of a "hack" but you could check the server protocol and check for the existence of the characters "HTTPS" in the protocol? :

```
<?php 
$protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
$protocol = substr($protocol,0,5); //will return something like HTTP/ or HTTPS
if(preg_match("^HTTPS^",$protocol)){
echo "ITS HTTPS";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

The best bet is as follows

```
<?php if( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ){  /* HTTPS */ } else{ /* NOT SO HTTPS */ } ?>
```